# Sort Enum.values() alphabetically and the add them to a Spinner ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, enums

I'm developing an Android application that works with a Web service.

I want to sort alphabetically `Enum.values()` by its description.

I have this `Enum`:

```
public enum Stature
{
    tall (0, MSDApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.stature_tall)),
    average(1, MSDApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.stature_average)),
    small(2, MSDApplication.getAppContext().getString(R.string.stature_small));

    private final int stature;
    private final String statureString;

    Stature(int anStature, String anStatureString) { stature = anStature; statureString = anStatureString; }

    public int getValue() { return stature; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return statureString; }
}
```

Maybe, this is not the best choice to use an `Enum`, but I'm very new on Java development.

**Do you know how can I sort it alphabetically using its `statureString`?**

I want to do this because I want to use these `Enum.values()` on an `ArrayAdapter`:

```
mSpinStature.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Stature>(mActivity, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Stature.values()));
```

And I want to get the `Stature` selected item here:

```
private OnItemSelectedListener listener = new OnItemSelectedListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long aid)
    {
        if (parent.equals(mSpinStature))
        {
            Stature item = (Stature)parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
            Log.v("TAG", item.toString() + item.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
    {
    }

};
```

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about adding a method to the enum

```
enum Stature {
    tall, average, small;

    public static Stature[] getSortedVaules() {
        Stature[] statures = values();
        Arrays.sort(statures, EnumByNameComparator.INSTANCE);
        return statures;
    }

    private static class EnumByNameComparator implements Comparator<Enum<?>> {

        public static final Comparator<Enum<?>> INSTANCE = new EnumByNameComparator();

        public int compare(Enum<?> enum1, Enum<?> enum2) {
            return enum1.name().compareTo(enum2.name());
        }

    }

}

public class StatureTest {

    @Test
    public void getSortedValues() {
        Stature[] normalValues = Stature.values();
        Assert.assertEquals(Stature.tall, normalValues[0]);
        Assert.assertEquals(Stature.average, normalValues[1]);
        Assert.assertEquals(Stature.small, normalValues[2]);

        Stature[] sortedVaules = Stature.getSortedVaules();
        Assert.assertEquals(Stature.average, sortedVaules[0]);
        Assert.assertEquals(Stature.small, sortedVaules[1]);
        Assert.assertEquals(Stature.tall, sortedVaules[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a java.text.Collator if you want Locale-specific (case insensitive) order and not the unicode codepoints as order.

Comment: If you change `return enum1.name().compareTo(enum2.name());` with `return enum1.toString().compareTo(enum2.toString());` it works!!

Answer (score 0):

Enums are sorted by declaration presedence. So the easiest way would be to declare them in desired order.

You could also try using Comparator interface implementing compare method.