# How to sort a set of maps inside an other map in java?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have an issue with sorting labels in a complex object composed by maps.

```
Map<Class<? extends Fiche>, Map<String, Map<Family, Set<Map<ObjectField, DetailsField>>>>> Fields = new HashMap<>();
```

Well, what I am trying to sort is the key `ObjectField` which is an Enum that contains the label of the field, by sorting this, I will get labels in alphabetic order.

The problem is that I don't know how to access to the Map containing `ObjectField` and `DetailsField`, the only object I have is Fields.

I found something about sorting Map in Java 8 but it concerns sorting Integer, and I have Maps of objects. Does anybody have an Idea to resolve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: HashMap is usually a bad choice for sorting elements as it uses its own algorithm to decide the store location.

Comment: Im wondering if you should create a new data structure this. Some level of abstraction. Seems your parameterized types are leading you towards confusion.

Comment: @MaxZoom I totally agree with you, I'm thinking about replace the last map by a treeMap but I'm not sure if there will not be any imact on the code.

Comment: @user489041 This is the problem, the old code was made to show all data, now I should order this data. It's not the same specification any more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to store data in a Map alphabetically? Java [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is exactly for this. A TreeMap and HashMap can be used essentially the same, but they store their internal information slightly differently. You should only have to change your initializers to keep the code compiling.

Comment: Nice idea, but the key is an Enum thant contains many variables, and I want to sort the key (Enum) depending on the id of this Enum, is it possible?

Comment: You could try creating a Map<String, Enum> to sort the Enum. Add values to the Map like `mapOfValues.put(currEnum.toString(), currEnum);` This would give you a Map that has the Enums, and their names, organized alphabetically. That would for sure give you an organized Map. Also check out this question, it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230233/sort-enum-values-alphabetically-and-the-add-them-to-a-spinner-arrayadapter

Answer (score 1):

The data model you are using can be represented as:

```
A -> B -> C -> [D -> E]
```

And your question is how to sort by `D`. Given `D` is four levels deep in your structure you will need to provide keys for `A`, `B` and `C` to be able to find the collection of `D -> E` maps to sort. There's no magic to that: you can't get to the third level without having values for the first three - that's the nature of a map.

Once you have a `Set<Map<D,E>>`, sorting by `D` can be interpreted as iterating through all `(D,E)` pairs in the natural order of `D`. This can be achieved as follows:

```
Set<Map<D,E>> setOfMaps;
setOfMaps.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
    ...
```

This produces a `Stream<Map.Entry<D,E>>` which you can then process with a `forEach` or collector as required.

As a comment, it's likely that your code would be clearer if you encapsulated some part of your data structure in a class rather than relying entirely on collections.